# Semantic Grids mixins creating massive selectors

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I am using SCSS for the first time (I've used LESS is the past) and using the Foundation framework. Im using the Semantic grid mixins but I've found its creating massive selectors when I view them in the Chrome inspector. Is this normal?

Below is an example.

`.top_bar .information_for_agencies, .top_bar .registration, header[role="banner"] .branding, header[role="banner"] .branding .logo, header[role="banner"] .branding .tagline, header[role="banner"] div[role="navigation"], footer[role="contentinfo"] section, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.full_width div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.two_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.two_columns div[role="main"] aside[role="complementary"], body.three_columns div[role="main"] section.adverts, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"], body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] header img.top_masthead, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_left, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content img.top_right, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.left_align, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.right_align, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] div.content figure.full_width, body.three_columns div[role="main"] article[role="article"] footer img.bottom_masthead, body.three_columns div[role="main"] aside[role="complementary"], body.homepage div[role="main"] header h1, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container .video_holder, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .personal_details label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .form_actions label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .hero_container form .form_actions .input_action, body.homepage div[role="main"] .reasons ul li, body.homepage div[role="main"] .testimonials h4, body.homepage div[role="main"] .testimonials ul blockquote, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .personal_details label, body.homepage div[role="main"] .register form .extra_info label {
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding: 0 15px;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just started using foundation with sass recently and I'm not seeing that. What does your app.scss and _settings.scss and config.rb files look like?
Have you been using @extend extensively? 
What happens is when you use @extend, it combines the selectors that have similar properties. 
So if you have:

```
.TestMe {
  color: blue;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px; }

.hello {
  @extend .TestMe
  width: 100px; }
```

would be combined to this css:

```
.TestMe, .hello {
  color: blue;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.hello {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you must be using `@extend` rather than @include.  The former is not a SASS mixin, the latter is.

You say you're using a mixin, but a mixin won't create massive selectors like that, but it will result in snippets of CSS being duplicated in the generated files.

A way to remember the difference is that `@extend` will extend your CSS selectors, as @keith73 describes, whereas `@include` will include more CSS.

Comment: If you're not using `@extend` yourself in those places then check the SCSS source for the semantic grid mixins you're using.  That must be where `@extend` is being used.  So you'd be doing lots of extend unwittingly, when you think you're just doing `@include`.  There's probably not much you can do about it.